# SQL case statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have a SQL Server stored proc that contains a CASE statement. However, I need to append the values if multiple conditions are true.

So if a particular record has an **Invalid Date** And **Mileage exceeded**, I would like both values to be displayed in the ***NotArchiveableReason*** column.

How would I accomplish that?

```
, CASE 
    WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date'
    WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage exceeded'
    WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 'Status code is Review'
    Else 'Unknown issue'
    END
    As NotArchiveableReason
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to concatenate results like `Invalid Date, Mileage Exceeded` then you may be looking for something like this.

```
ISNULL(
    NULLIF(
        STUFF(
            CASE WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN ', Invalid Date' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN ', Mileage exceeded' ELSE '' END
            + CASE WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN ', Status code is Review' ELSE '' END
        , 1, 2, '')
    ,'')
, 'Unknown issue')
As NotArchiveableReason
```

The `STUFF()` removes the leading comma. The `NULLIF()` converts the empty string to null. The `ISNULL()` will populate "Unknown Issue" when none of the `CASE` statement conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

```
, CASE WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date ' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage exceeded ' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 'Status code is Review ' ELSE '' END
+ CASE WHEN NOT
       (   DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate
       AND MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed
       AND LossStatusCode != 'R') THEN 'Unknown issue ' ELSE '' END
    As NotArchiveableReason
```

Comment: when I try your code, I get some records with all 4 combinations ('Invalid Date Mileage exceeded Status code is Review Unknown issue')

Answer (score 1):

```
,  CASE   WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date '        ELSE '' END
+  CASE   WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage exceeded ' ELSE '' END
+  CASE   WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 'Status code is Review '      ELSE '' END
   CASE   WHEN DateOfLoss >= PolicyStartDate OR MilesDriven <= TotalMilesAllowed
                OR LossStatusCode = 'R'
          THEN 'Unknown issue' END                              As NotArchiveableReason
```

Comment: did you intend to put a '+' in front of your last CASE statement?

Comment: @Csharp Yes I will concatinate the the strings returned by multiple Case statement. in all the Else Clause I have added Empty String with no Space '' but the actual returned Value 'Invalid Date ' has a trailing space .

Comment: Because in Case Statement if you are checking against all conditions in one Case statement, it stops looking for further WHENs as soon as it get the 1st hit, and returns the very 1st  THEN 'Value'  where WHEN is true, Concatinating Case Statements like this force check against all the Cases even One or None is true :)

Answer (score 0):

How about expand the result set and let the application handle it

```
, CASE WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as InvalidDate
, CASE WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MileageExceeded
, CASE WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as StatusCodeIsReview
```

Then if all is zero it is an unknown issue?

**EDIT**

You can try this then. This is using an inner select to first find the problems and then combine it afterwards. In this sollution you can add many different checks in the inner select, and then combine them as you like in the outer.

```
select case when tmp.InvalidDate is null and tmp.MileageExceeded is null and tmp.StatusCodeIsReview is null then 'Unknown issue' else
stuff
(
    (
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(tmp.InvalidDate, ''), '') + 
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(tmp.MileageExceeded, ''), '') + 
        COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(tmp.StatusCodeIsReview, ''), '')), 1, 2, '')
end as NotArchiveableReason from
(
    select *
    , CASE WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date' ELSE NULL END as InvalidDate
    , CASE WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage Exceeded' ELSE NULL END as MileageExceeded
    , CASE WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 'Status Code Is Review' ELSE NULL END as StatusCodeIsReview
    from MyTest
) as tmp
```

Comment: this solution is going to return more columns than I want... (especially if I add more conditions to the stored proc)

Comment: But if you add more conditions to the SP you also just add many more combinations of "issues" and make it much more complex to concatinate!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go with 3 case statements and then in a new query CONCAT them?

```
, CASE 
WHEN DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date'
END as 1

WHEN MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage exceeded'
END as 2

WHEN LossStatusCode != 'R' THEN 'Status code is Review'
END as 3

 select 1+2+3 As NotArchiveableReason
```