# Creating a complex case statement in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I am trying to convert an if statement into a SQL case statement and not having much luck getting the logic to work correctly. (My question is an updated version of [SQL case statement in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20125773/72324)

```
if LossStatusCode == 'R' Then 'Item has been reviewed.'  

ELseif //if  LossStatusCode != 'R'
    DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate THEN 'Invalid Date'  
    MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed THEN 'Mileage exceeded'

Else // if (LossStatusCode != 'R') && Date is valid && Mileage is Valid)
    LossStatusCode != 'R' Then 'Status code is Review.'
```

How would I convert the above logic into a SQL Case statement?

Answer (score 2):

```
select case when LossStatusCode = 'R' then 'Item has been reviewed.'
            when DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate and MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed then 'Invalid Date, Mileage exceeded'
            when DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate then 'Invalid Date' 
            when MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed then 'Mileage exceeded'
            else 'Status code is Review.'
       end
```

Comment: That one seems to be easy... however, if (DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate) && (MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed) then I need a string that says "Invalid Date, Mileage exceeded"

Comment: Thats not going to work.... "DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate and MilesDriven > TotalMilesAllowed".... this could have more conditions added in the future... so your suggestion could get very long

Comment: @Csharp - You could use a nested CASE to handle several `DateOfLoss < PolicyStartDate` conditions. Would that help?